# Restricciones de acceso a carpetas en Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

Estoy intentando crear restricciones de acceso a una carpeta dentro de un curso **Moodle** mediante un **Script**. Esta restricción debe ser para grupos de usuarios y sino perteneces a dicho grupo no puedes ver los recursos existentes en dicha carpeta.

El funcionamiento que quiero hacer mediante programación es como el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado información y es muy escasa y en la documentación sólo pone cómo hacerlo desde la web [enlace](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Groups#Restricting_an_activity.2C_resource_or_course_topic_to_a_particular_group).

Sé cómo crear grupos, carpetas y secciones mediante programación desde script, pero no consigo identificar las tablas que hay que utilizar para hacer estas restricciones o cuales son los pasos a seguir.

Si alguien conoce cómo hacerlo o tiene algún ejemplo o documentación que me pueda servir, será una gran ayuda para mi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de buscar y probar algunas cosas, he encontrado una solución que funciona, y consiste en modificar el campo `availavility` de la tabla `mdl_course_modules` para añadirle la restricción de acceso.

He creado una función que se encarga de crear este permiso, y es la siguiente:

```
 /**
 * Se crean las restricciones de acceso a las seccion para solo usuarios que pertenezcan al grupo
 *
 * @param $course curso en que esta la seccion a restringir acceso
 * @param $sectionid id de la seccion a restringir acceso
 * @param $groupid id del grupo que tendra acceso
 * @param $module id del modulo a restringir de la tabla mdl_modules
 *
 */
    function grantPermission($course, $sectionid, $groupid, $module ){

        global $DB;

        $restriction = '{"op":"&","c":[{"type":"group","id":'. $groupid .'}],"showc":[true]}';

        $cm= $DB->get_record('course_modules', array('course' => $course , 'section' => $sectionid, 'module' => $module ), '*', MUST_EXIST);

        $course_module = new stdClass();
        $course_module->id = $cm->id;
        $course_module->course = $course;
        $course_module->section = $sectionid;
        $course_module->availability = $restriction;

        $res = $DB->update_record('course_modules', $course_module);

        if($res)
            rebuild_course_cache($course, true);    

        return $res;
    }
```